# How to preserve object keys in lodash filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have an array

```
const sampleObject = {Color: "Blue", Size: "39, 41"}
```

Using Lodash's _.filter when I try

```
_.filter(sampleObject, (entry) => entry !== 'Blue')
```

I get

```
['39, 41']
```

But my desired result is

```
{Size: '39, 41'}
```

```js
const sampleObject = {
  Color: "Blue",
  Size: "39, 41"
}
const filtered = _.filter(sampleObject, (entry) => entry !== 'Blue')
console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are trying to omit the object property `Color` when the `Color` is not `"Blue"`? Are you filtering a single object or filtering an array of objects? What are you actually doing in your application?

Comment: That's not an array, it's an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for [`_.pickBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pickBy)?

```js
const sampleObject = {
  Color: "Blue",
  Size: "39, 41"
}
const filtered = _.pickBy(sampleObject, (value,key) => value !== 'Blue')
console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems odd you need to do this, but you can use fromEntries and entries to do it

```js
const sampleObject = {Color: "Blue", Size: "39, 41"}
const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(sampleObject).filter(x => x[1] !== 'Blue'));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just that one property in a new object, grab it directly:

```js
const sampleObject = {Color: "Blue", Size: "39, 41"};

const result = {Size: sampleObject.Size};

console.log(result);
```

Or if you need the key to be dynamic:

```js
const sampleObject = {Color: "Blue", Size: "39, 41"};

const key = "Size";

const result = {[key]: sampleObject[key]};

console.log(result);
```